# What is the difference between $CMD and eval $CMD?

Tags: bash

We had code like this in a shell script:

```
CMD="docker container create \
    --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
    --network $NETWORK \
    nginx:1.17 \
    nginx-debug -g 'daemon off;'"
$CMD
```

when we executed the script, it did not work as expected. The container gives following error:

```
nginx: invalid option: "off;'"
```

Then we changed to:

```
eval $CMD
```

in the bash script and then it started working! I'd like to understand what is the difference between the two.

Comment: Very relevant, if not a dupe: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946)

Comment: Also [Trying to use sed within eval statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645628/100397)